# EF Core Sql execution order needs to change

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables related by a foreign key. the foreign key is nullable so the relationship is not required. The relationship is also a one to one. Here is the EF model definition

```
    public class SignTypeLink
    {
    [Key]    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    }
    public class Image
    {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]    
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public SignTypeLink SignTypeLink { get; set; }
    }

            builder.Entity<EF.Sign>()
                .HasOne(stl => stl.Image)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<EF.Sign(stl => stl.ImageId)
                .HasPrincipalKey<EF.Image>(pi => pi.Id);
```

1. I add a sign to the database without an image and savechanges works fine.
2. I add a sign to the database with an image and savechanges works fine.
3. I want to delete said image and save changes, I do this by setting ImageID in the sign to null and entity state to changed and i also set the image entity state to deleted. This FAILS due to referential constraints. This should be fine since i am making the foreign key null and also deleting the record. The reason this fails is the sql execution order or EF core. It decided to delete the Image record first. Then update my sign. Like so

```
DELETE FROM [Myschema].[Image]
WHERE [Id] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

UPDATE [Myschema].[Sign] SET [Quantity] = @p2, [ImageId] = @p3
WHERE [Id] = @p4;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

this sql fails because of the constraint. My problem is why EF core chose this order. If these sql statements were reversed we would all be fine.

Comment: How about you show us the code for (3)?

Comment: One of the FKs is redundant (one-to-one need only one FK). With the presented model you have created 2 circular relationships, hence all the issues. If you need one-to-one, choose the principal and dependent roles and remove one of the FKs.

Comment: removing the second foreign key caused the same error.
    public class Image
    {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]    
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }